# In Python, how do you know what argument types to pass to poorly documented functions?

Tags: python, function, dynamic, types

I'm relatively new to Python. I come predominantly from a C++ background, and C++ is a strongly and statically typed language, hence type checking is done at compile time and a function's prototype is self-documenting with respect to type information. Using a third-party library is often straightforward as long as they provide API reference pages such as those rendered by Doxygen. Upon finding a useful function, one can just look up its arguments' types and learn how to construct them. For example, I can easily figure out how to do most things in WxWidgets just by perusing the [reference pages](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/annotated.html).

I'm currently working on a project in Python in which I need to manipulate font files. For this I'm using the FontTools package, but the documentation is lacking, and there are few tutorials online. I've been trying to glean as much as I can from the docstrings.

The question that's puzzling me right now, is how I'm meant to actually do anything when I don't know what types any function takes?

Comment: unfortunately you might just have to look through the source

Comment: There are a few things coming soon like type annotations that will help with this, but maybe dynamically typed languages just aren't for you.

Comment: To some degree *duck typing* is pretty important, meaning the exact type isn't as important and the function will actually handle a number of compatible types. Of course, if the documentation doesn't even give you enough of a hint as to roughly narrow down a few possible types, it's really a badly written library.

Comment: Often you can guess by reading the function and parameter names, but in general if the documentation is poor then the naming probably is too, and you'll have to read the source and work it out.

Comment: A poorly documented function is just that - poorly documented.  If you have a C or C++ library that takes void pointers and casts them, you would also have the same problem if the documentation was poor.  The only way to figure out how to use the library at that point is to read the code.

Comment: Are you sure your question is Python specific? Types is only part of interface, and statically typed language does not makes any interface good just by it's typing properties. If you want to ask _how to use poorly designed or poorly documented APIs?_ the answer are always the same - experiment or study a code to figure it out yourself and wrap it in some kind of adapter for easier usage. No need to blame Python (or other non-static languages) for incompetence of library authors.

Comment: Another source of information is to look at examples of using the library/package. I've used [Nullege](http://nullege.com), which is a search engine for Python source code, many times for this. It's often useful even if the API documentation is fairly decent because it will allow you to observe common patterns of usage.